# Why does useContext work without Context.Provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can you explain me why useContext() works for me if I don't wrap my components with Context.Provider? I just exported result of "createContext(someValues)" with predefined values and called useContext(exportedContext) in component and it works. Every tutorial tells me to wrap components. Has something changed in React?

Comment: It works but you are given `undefined` as a value, I guess it's a compromise between DX and trying to keep the app without crashing in production.

Comment: what do you mean - undefined as a value? I can successfully read a values (predefined) from context via useContext hook

Comment: Oh, right, I was thinking only about `createContext()` with no default value, that gives `undefined`.

Comment: I don't think this has ever changed, it's just that using context without wrapping your component is kind of useless, you could just export a constant and import it elsewhere without using a context in the first place.

Comment: @JakubKotrs it is not useless. Think of this: context holds some values and initialised with the sensible defaults. Somewhere in your component tree you want those defaults to be used, so you just do `useContext`. And where you want them to dynamically change based on certain behaviour, you wrap that subtree in a `Context.Provider` that provides new `value` (overriding the default). 
Context in React is not just a state management mechanism. It is more of a dependency injection mechanism. If you want it to be a state store, then wrap your tree in a provider and boom now it is a state store.

Comment: @avepr You right and I have used it this way as well since I made that comment.

Answer (score 10):

All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes. In other words, If you don't wrap your components with `Context.Provider` they won't get re-rendered when the `someValues` in `createContext(someValues)` changes. You will get the initial value that you set only in the first render.

Demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-provider-example-hl4e4f)

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your answer. Are you sure about that? Because as I see, it doesn't re-render if I change context value. Only way to re-render is to put into context value state with method setState.

Comment: Here is a demo example that I've prepared for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-provider-example-hl4e4f
I hope that helps :)

Comment: Great answer!, We need more quick examples like these when it comes to closing the gap between class & functional component differences

Answer (score 5):

`React.Context` always worked this way.
If a component is not wrapped in the `Context.Provider` it will receive the default value that was set when the context was created.

Provider's job is to override the default values, essentially providing dependency injection mechanism to React component tree.

Here is a good answer from React team: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17912